# How select a text in websites and then do direct a google search with parameters in autohotkey

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, google-search

I want if I **select a text** in a webpage that I can do a Google search in **one shortcut click** on my keyboard.

It must do this:

- copy the **selected text** to **clipboard**
- goto the **address bar** in the browser.
- 1 - write https://www.google.com/search?q=
- 2 - + write the **selected text** in the **address bar**
- 3 - + write google parameters **search?q=selected text** + **&num=100** + **&lr=lang_de** + **&hl=de**
- and than together with 1+2+3 - do **direct a google search** in browsers like chrome/firefox/explorer/edge

the code must be written in **autohotkey** languages for windows 10.

the AHK code must be like:

```
; + = Shift
; # = Win (Windows logo key)
; ! = Alt
; ^ = Ctrl 


^s:: ; press ctrl+s to do a google search
send ^c ; copy the selected text to clipboard
text = %clipboard%
send https://www.google.com/search?q=%text%&num=100&lr=lang_de&hl=de
send {enter}
return
```

This code does not goes **automatically** to the **address bar** and then do a Google search.

I need a code that does do this **automatically** in **one shortcut click**

Comment: I've made some changes to correct your spelling mistakes, but you've rolled it back - I made the changes to make sure your question is clear. Not sure why you didn't accept those changes.

Comment: "I need a code that does do this automatically in one shortcut click" - I am going to issue a downvote, since you are asking us to provide you code, it is irrelevant in my eyes if you eventually figured out how to do it yourself and ended up answering your own question.

Comment: Ramhound, **I am new here** and **need to learn** how everything works. I did later figured it out by myself and did answer self my question so that other people can use this code.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what isn't working for you as your question lacks a lot of detail - I can only assume that Google Chrome doesn't execute.

```
send ^c 
text = %clipboard%
Run C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe  https://www.google.com/search?q=%text%&num=100&lr=lang_de&hl=de
send {enter}
return
```

Comment: I haven't close your question?

Answer (score 0):

This code works in **all browsers**, you can **select any text** in **any website**

Press <kbd>F2</kbd> to do direct a **Google search** from the **selected text**. [us] [50 results]

Use this AHK script:

```
; ^ = Ctrl
; + = Shift
; ! = Alt
; # = Win (Windows logo key)
GroupAdd, Browser, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1 ; Chrome or Iron
GroupAdd, Browser, ahk_class IEFrame            ; Internet Explorer
GroupAdd, Browser, ahk_class MozillaWindowClass ; FireFox
GroupAdd, Browser, ahk_class ApplicationFrameWindow ; Edge

#If WinActive("ahk_group Browser")

f2:: ; press f2 for a google search
send ^c ;copy the selected text to clipboard memory
sleep 150
send ^t ; CTRL+t this will make a new tab + go to address bar  - use CTRL+L for the active tab + go to address bar
sleep 150
text1 = https://www.google.com/search?q=
text2 = %clipboard% ;selected text
text3 =  &lr=lang_us&hl=us&num=50 ; google parameters

clipboard=%text1%%text2%%text3%
sleep 150
send ^v ; paste the selected text 
sleep 250
send {enter}
clipboard=%text2%
return
```

Comment: I don't think the `text3` parameters are required. I can go to https://google.com/search?q=example and it'll execute my search no problem. I believe you can use those parameters to change the language or number of results though.

Comment: **text3** parameters you will need - if you want to make more scripts for example **f2::(United States-50results)** and **f3::(germany-100results)**